# $('.object').click(function(){}); – causing buttons to disappear?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, crash, click

I've recently uploaded a WordPress website for a client. At first it was fine, but there's been 3 instances now, where after 12 – 24 hours of normalcy it will start being strange. For e.g. the downarrow (makes page scroll down), or it becomes invisible but functions.

I've pared down the code (ie remove unused plugins, removed unnecessary scripts, thereby reducing chances of conflict). That seems to have helped.

At this point, the website is stable: maisonsivo.ca

Having said that, the last time there was a glitch, the downbutton was the ONLY one to fail : except for the first instance of the downbutton on the first page, every other button was invisible – still there and functional but invisible. The fix: stating specifically in CSS that it should have visibility: inherit, opacity: 1, etc.

So onwards; I'm curious if anyone sees a problem with the code here for the downbutton:

```
$(function() {
    $('.glissante').click(function(){
    $j(window).scrollTo( {top:'+=400px', left:'0'} , 
                         {duration:500, interrupt:false });
    });
});
```

It uses the ScrollTo jQuery, linked in functions.php.

Is the browser somehow not liking the fact that there are multiple instances with the same class and function?

Would it help to write it another way? 
Like using if ... hasClass (though I'm not familiar with it)

Context: the website is hosted on a "Managed Wordpress account" on GoDaddy

Thanks for any input.

Comment: No offense, but you're not familiar with `hasClass()` but you `haveClients`? On a more serious note, if your buttons are all there but invisible, something set the to be invisible. take out code a little at a time till the behaviour stops then inspect the last thing you removed to find the cause

Comment: before invoking the click event, check $('.glissante').length to see if the element even exists.

Comment: @DinoMyte the shown code does not invoke the click event...the OP is binding to the click event which is valid regardless of whether the element exists or not and couldnt cause the button to be set to `display:none;`

Comment: OP, why do you use `$` on one line then use `$j` on the very next line? are you using multiple versions of jQuery in your project?

Comment: @DelightedD0D I usually use $, I found that with the copy of scrollTo the theme developers have included it didn't seem to work. I looked at their codes for scrollTo and copied the same $j... in fact that was the other thing I wanted to ask about.

Comment: @DelightedD0D As to my ignorance of hasClass, no I haven't gotten around to that – hasn't needed it so far. I do a mix of graphic design and web work, background in GD.

Comment: The use of `$j` working while `$` does not would lead me to believe that your theme has multiple versions of jQuery loaded, likely because `scrollTo`  requires a different version than the rest of the theme. This isnt necessarily the cause but Id look closely at the setup to see if the multiple versions are causing issues. They can if not used properly. Beyond that, we cant really help you, youll need to take out code *a little at a time* till the behaviour stops then inspect the last thing you removed to find the cause

Comment: @DelightedD0D thanks, I will look at modifying it and sticking it the same copy.